# Is there any way to debug events from the Ajax UpdatePanel?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, asp.net-ajax

I am using the Ajax UpdatePanel for all my webpages, but am not able to debug events from the panel. Is there any way to do this? Can it be done with Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

[FireBug](http://www.getfirebug.com/) is a nice tool that might help you debug AJAX requests.